# How to add chart js legends in ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, chart.js

Hello i am new to ember ie its been 2 months since i started using it, so in my ember project i have included a chart js library using https://github.com/aomran/ember-cli-chart the thing is in my x-axis labels, since the label string is very big i replace the original big string with a,b,c ..etc using

```
ticks: {
        callback: function(tick, index, array) {
            var alphabet = alphabets: ["a","b","c"];
            if(tick.length > 20){
                return alphabet[index];
                 }
       }
```

So because of the above function my actual string doesnt get displayed rather a,b,c gets disaplyed
[image]

So now i want a legend or something to provide description for the a,b,c labels ie something like

a: "this is actual long string"
b: " this is another long string"

I came across customize legends in chart.js but i dont know how to configure it with ember

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd the same issue with you, every item has a name, value and code. The name is larger than 20 characters.

I've provided codes as labels and names as tooltip. So my data:

```
data:{
  labels: items.map((item)=>{return Ember.get(item, labelName);}),
  datasets: [{
    borderColor: BORDER_COLORS,
    backgroundColor: BACKGROUND_COLORS,
    data: items.mapBy(propertyName)
  }]
}
```

And my tooltip options:

```
tooltips: {
  callbacks:{
    title: (tooltipItems)=>{
      let index = tooltipItem[0].index;
      return Ember.get(this.get('items')[index], tooltipName);
    }
  }
}
```

This solved my problem. I've tried legends but long names in legend fields are not seemed good to me.